# Why there is an error to Read avro file using Python

Tags: python

```
import avro.schema
import json
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

reader = DataFileReader(open('Atlas_1_gsmmap.avro', "rb"), DatumReader())
```

error:

```
b = ord(self.read(1))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

Please, help me to solve that

Comment: What is the `read` fynction? Can you give a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please ?

Comment: `self.read`? if you use self it means this code is inside a class, but we don't see any class in your code.